# pytest fixture 'dog' not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

Say, for instance, I'm calling the following code using pytest

```
class Dog:
   def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed

def test_dog_age(dog):
    dog_age = dog.age
    assert dog_age == 7
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dog1 = Dog('rex', 7, 'labrador')
    test_dog_age(dog1)
```

I'm getting an error saying

> E       fixture 'dog' not found
> available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
> use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

Comment: If you provide a parameter to a test function, pytest considers it a fixture and looks for a fixture of that name, thus the message - otherwise the test function shall not have any parameters. And you cannot call a test function directly - you have to call pytest, and it will discover the tests. Check the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery).

Comment: Im initiating the dog down below. How would I go through doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this clearer: pytest basically works by collecting all tests it finds, applying all fixtures and hooks that are defined and executing the tests.

In your case, your test would look something like:

```py
def test_dog_age():
    dog = Dog('rex', 7, 'labrador')
    assert dog.age == 7
```

And you would call `pytest` at the command line to exceute the test. You can also call it with the specific test file, say `pytest test_dog.py`.

Any parameter you add to the test function is handled as a test fixture, and if no fixture is found with that name (fixtures are looked up by name only), you get the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

def function should not start with "test" or "test_".
`def test_dog_age(dog):` -->`def dog_age_test(dog):`

Answer (score -1):

There was an unexpected indentation on line 1.